# Prevent WebGL Three.js container to catch scrolling events

Tags: javascript, css, dom, three.js

I have a full-screen three.js application as background and want to put text as overlay on it, which I want to be able to scroll.

My problem is that apparently the three.js WebGL container **catches all the scroll events** and does not allow the overlaying content to be scrolled.

The three.js-application is a `<canvas>` element, my CSS:

```
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

This is the the body and the parent `<div>` element of the content which should be scrollable.

```
body {
   display:block;
}

.page-content {
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 0;
}
```

- Both are immediate children of body.
- The script gets executed after the content.

**How can I prevent the Three.js container catching scrolling (e.g. scrollwheel) events and forward them to the `.page-content` div?**

Comment: Which controls are you using. I thing @Rush2112 his answer will most likely solve your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a controls issue actually.

you want to set: `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`

Otherwise, [the controls will set `document` as it's domain](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L20) and catch all events.

So whichever controls you use, add the `renderer.domElement` portion to it

Comment: I'm not using any controls, thanks for your answer anyway. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Wilt, my current work project is C# so I'm not in full JS mode :P

Comment: this is the actual solution (when using OrbitControls). Worked perfectly in chrome, thanks!